# Sort a field of each object in a list with LINQ

Tags: linq

Is is possible to sort an item in a IEnumerable list using LINQ?

For example:

```
        IEnumerable<sample> sam = new List<sample>()
        {
            new sample{ id = 1, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{5,6,1}},
            new sample{ id = 2, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{2,9}},
            new sample{ id = 3, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{8,3,7}},
            new sample{ id = 4, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{8,4,3}},
            new sample{ id = 5, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{5,1,7}},
            new sample{ id = 6, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{6,9,7}}
        };
```

The expected output from the sample given above would be the sorted values in List.
Expected output is:

```
sample{ id = 1, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{1,5,6}},
sample{ id = 2, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{2,9}},
sample{ id = 3, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{3,7,8},
sample{ id = 4, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{3,4,8}},
sample{ id = 5, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{1,5,7}},
sample{ id = 6, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{6,7,9}}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 sam.All(p => { p.list.Sort(); return true; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((List<sample>)sam).ForEach(s => s.list.Sort());
```

Answer (score 0):

The general shape for LINQ is that it does not change the original data. For example, if we have a list

```
var ints = new  List<int>{5,6,1};
```

and use linq to 'sort it'

```
var sorted = ints.OrderBy();
```

we end up with two lists

```
ints => { 5,6,1}
sorted => {1,5,6}
```

In your above example, it depends on what you want the output to be

If you want a new list of samples where the list is sorted then you can use

```
var newSampleList = samples.Select( sam => new Sample { 
                                                 id = sam.id, 
                                                 name = sam.name, 
                                                 list = new List<int>(sam.list.OrderBy())
                                   });
```

If you do not want to create a new list but want to sort the values in place it is not really what LINQ is intended for but it can be done using something like AVD's answer to execute functionality on each member (in this case call Sort on the list).

NOTE: This will only work if sample.list is defined as a List() as Sort() only exists on List<>. If defined as IList or IEnumerable it will not work.