# How to sort an IEnumerable object by a nested IEnumerable object?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort a field of each object in a list with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241199/sort-a-field-of-each-object-in-a-list-with-linq)

I have this collection:

```
    IEnumerable<sample> sam = new List<sample>()
    {
        new sample{ id = 1, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{5,6,1}},
        new sample{ id = 2, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{2,9}},
        new sample{ id = 3, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{8,3,7}},
        new sample{ id = 4, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{8,4,3}},
        new sample{ id = 5, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{5,1,7}},
        new sample{ id = 6, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{6,9,7}}
    };
```

How can I sort this using LINQ so that the output is:

```
     new sample{ id = 2, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{2,9}},
     new sample{ id = 5, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{5,1,7}},
     new sample{ id = 1, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{5,6,1}},
     new sample{ id = 6, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{6,9,7}}
     new sample{ id = 3, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{8,3,7}},
     new sample{ id = 4, name = "sample 1", list = new List<int>{8,4,3}},
```

This is sort by 'list' by the way.

Thanks

Comment: Doing homework?? Also in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241199/sort-a-field-of-each-object-in-a-list-with-linq/12241489#12241489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the LINQ to order `sam` by the first item of the `list` property (I gather that's what you're after, right?):

```
IEnumerable<sample> orderedSam = sam.OrderBy(item => item.list.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Changing the operator to `FirstOrDefault()` should guard against exceptions when sorting by an empty list.

Comment: Yes something like that... thanks a lot