# C# Sorting IEnumerable of IEnumerables

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
public class MyObj 
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
  public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially I end up with an IEnumerable of sections, which in turn contains an IEnumerable of items. Both the list of sections and the items need to be sorted by their respective SortOrder properties.

I know that I can sort the sections by doing `obj.Sections.OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)` but then I can't work out how to sort the items within each section too.

The context is that I'm writing a Sort function that takes an unsorted MyObj and returns one with both the sections and the items sorted.

```
public MyObj Sort(MyObj unsortedObj)
{
  var sortedObj = unsortedObj.....

  return sortedObj;
}
```

The expected data structure would be something like this:

```
- Section1
  - Item1
  - Item2
- Section2
  - Item1
  - Item2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an IEnumerable object by a nested IEnumerable object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241427/how-to-sort-an-ienumerable-object-by-a-nested-ienumerable-object)

Comment: `obj.Sections.OrderBy(s => s.SortOrder)` will not sort `Sections` it will return new `IOrderedEnumerable`

Comment: What is the expected result here? Do you want `Items` sorted inside each `Section` or for all `MyObj`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Updated with expected sorting

Comment: Can't we sort all the items in sections first and then sort the section itself? @SamWalpole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be convenient for you to add methods that creates copies of these objects except for one property being different:

```
// in MyObj
public MyObj WithSections(IEnumerable<Section> sections) =>
    new MyObj {
        Title = this.Title,
        Sections = sections
    };

// in Section
public Section WithItems(IEnumerable<Items> items) =>
    new Section {
        Title = this.Title,
        Items = items,
        SortOrder = this.SortOrder
    };
```

First, sort the sections

```
var sortedSections = unsortedObj.Sections.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder);
```

Then *for each of those sorted sections*, transform them with `Select` so that their items are also sorted:

```
var sortedSectionsAndItems = sortedSections.Select(x => x.WithItems(x.Items.OrderBy(y => y.SortOrder)));
```

Now you can return a `MyObj` with the sorted sections and items:

```
return unsortedObj.WithSections(sortedSectionsAndItems);
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Only modification I made was to make the methods static extensions. i.e. `public static MyObj WithSections(this MyObj obj, IEnumerable<Section> sections)`....